# Using Indy TCPClient/TCPServer to send picture from mobile XE8

Tags: delphi, mobile, indy, delphi-xe8

I have a simple mobile application written in Delphi XE8 that allows the user to take a picture and then send the picture to a server using Indy TCPClient/TCP Server.

I have scoured the forums and found numerous examples to send the data in a variety of ways. Every method I try results in an access violation or corrupt data on the server side.

My ultimate goal is to send a record containing a unique identifier, description and a picture(bitmap) from the client to the server.
But I'm starting out be trying to simply send a record with some text from a windows client to the server. I will then try to implement the solution into my mobile app.

```
type
  TSendRec = record
//    SONo: string;
    Text: string;
//    Bitmap: TBitMap;
  end
```

I have tried the following 3 methods as per the code below:

1. Send Using a Stream
2. Send using RawToBytes and `TIDBytes`.
3. Send a line of text using `Writeln` and `Readln`

When I try to send using a stream I get the following access violation:

> Project memorystream_server.exe raised the exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00409e46: write of address 0x0065d1bc

The error occurs when I try to access the value of `MiRec.Text` on the server side.

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(MiRec.Text);
```

So I assume the read of the `MIRec` is failing for some reason:

When I send using `RawToBytes`, no error message occurs but the value of `MIRec.Text` is garbage.

When I just send a line of text using `WriteLn`, the server receives and displays the data correctly and no access violation occurs.

I tried to follow examples that I have found from other posts on this issue. I would greatly appreciate any insight into what I am doing wrong.

Following are my client and server side code snippets:

**Client**

```
procedure TfrmMemoryStreamClient.btnSendClick2(Sender: TObject);
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  msRecInfo2: TIdMemoryBufferStream;
begin
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;

  MIRec.Text := 'Hello World';

  if rbSendStream.Checked then
  begin
    msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      msRecInfo.Write(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo, 0, False);
    finally
      msRecInfo.Free;
    end;
{
    msRecInfo2 := TIdMemoryBufferStream.Create(@MIRec, SizeOf(TSendRec));
    try
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo2);
    finally
      msRecInfo.Free;
    end;
}
  end
  else
  if rbSendBytes.Checked then
  begin
    Buffer := RawToBytes(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Buffer);
  end
  else
  if rbWriteLn.Checked then
  begin
    IdTCPClient1.Socket.WriteLn(Edit1.Text);
  end;

  IdTCPClient1.DisConnect;
end;
```

**Server**

```
procedure TStreamServerForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var sName: String;
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
begin

  if not chkReceiveText.Checked then
  begin
    try
      if chkReadBytes.Checked then
      begin
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, SizeOf(MIRec));
        BytesToRaw(Buffer, MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MiRec.Text);
      end
      else
      begin
        msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;

        try
          // does not read the stream size, just the stream data
          AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, SizeOf(MIRec), False);

          msRecInfo.Position := 0;
          msRecInfo.Read(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
          Memo1.Lines.Add(MiRec.Text);
        finally
          msRecInfo.Free;
        end;
{
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, -1, False);
        msRecInfo.Position := 0;
        msRecInfo.Read(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MiRec.Text);
}
      end;

      Memo1.Lines.Add('read File');
    except
      Memo1.Lines.Add('error in read File');
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    sName := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(sName);
  end;

  AContext.Connection.Disconnect;
end;
```

Comment: Delphi's string is a reference type. You are writing its pointer in the record, not the text.

Comment: Use a streaming library to stream the record. Like [this one](https://github.com/krystianbigaj/kblib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multithreaded component.  Its `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, and `OnExecute` events are triggered in the context of a worker thread.  As such, you MUST synchronize with the main UI thread when accessing UI controls, like your Memo.

Also, `String` is a compiler-managed data type, and `TBitmap` is an object.  Both store their data elsewhere in memory, so you cannot write a record containing such fields as-is.  You would be writing only the value of their data pointers, not writing the actual data being pointed at.  You need to serialize your record into a transmittable format on the sending side, and then deserialize it on the receiving side.  That means handling the record fields individually.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TSendRec = record
    SONo: string;
    Text: string;
    Bitmap: TBitMap;
  end;
```

Client

```
procedure TfrmMemoryStreamClient.btnSendClick2(Sender: TObject);
var
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MIRec.SONo := ...;
  MIRec.Text := 'Hello World';
  MIRec.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  ...
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    try
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(MIRec.SONo);
      IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn(MIRec.Text);
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        MIRec.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ms);
        IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
        IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    finally
      IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    MIRec.Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Server

```
procedure TStreamServerForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MIRec.SONo := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  MIRec.Text := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  MIRec.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms, -1, False);
      ms.Position := 0;
      MIRec.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MIRec.SONo);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MIRec.Text);
        // display MIRec.Bitmap as needed...
      end;
    end;
  finally
    MIRec.Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

Client

```
procedure TfrmMemoryStreamClient.btnSendClick2(Sender: TObject);
var
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  ms: TMemoryStream;

  procedure SendString(const S: String);
  var
    Buf: TIdBytes;
  begin
    Buf := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(S);
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Int32(Length(Buf)));
    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(Buf);
  end;

begin
  MIRec.SONo := ...;
  MIRec.Text := 'Hello World';
  MIRec.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  ...
  try
    IdTCPClient1.Connect;
    try
      SendString(MIRec.SONo);
      SendString(MIRec.Text);
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        MIRec.Bitmap.SaveToStream(ms);
        IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.LargeStream := True;
        IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(ms, 0, True);
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    finally
      IdTCPClient1.Disconnect;
    end;
  finally
    MIRec.Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Server

```
procedure TStreamServerForm.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  MIRec: TSendRec;
  ms: TMemoryStream;

  function RecvString: String;
  begin
    Result := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadString(
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt32,
      IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
  end;

begin
  MIRec.SONo := RecvString;
  MIRec.Text := RecvString;
  MIRec.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(ms, -1, False);
      ms.Position := 0;
      MIRec.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(ms);
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MIRec.SONo);
        Memo1.Lines.Add(MIRec.Text);
        // display MIRec.Bitmap as needed...
      end;
    end;
  finally
    MIRec.Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response, Remy. I implemented your solution in my Windows client and the server received all the data correctly. Therefore I duplicated the code into my Mobile application. The only difference I can see is that the bitmap is stored in a TImage component (which will eventually be a ListViewItem).

Comment: Are you using VCL or FMX in your Windows client? Just be careful, because VCL's `TBitmap` is VERY different than FMX's `TBitmap`. Make sure you are transmitting a consistent graphic format over the wire that both desktop and mobile platforms support. And be use to use proper thread synchronization when accessing a `TImage` component.

Comment: That would explain the problem I am having with regards to the Mobile Application. The Windows Client and server use TBitmap via VCL. The mobile app is using TBitmap from FMX. As a result when running the Mobile app I am getting an 'invalid bitmap' message when I load the stream on the Server Side.

Comment: Since the client will only ever be run from a mobile I changed the server to use FMX.Graphics instead of VCL.Graphics. On the mobile client side I changed 'MIRec.Bitmap.SaveToStream(msRecInfo)' to 'imgCameraView.Bitmap.SaveToStream(msRecInfo)'. However when I try to loadfromstream on the server side I get the following error: 'Cannot Create WIC Imaging Factory object for TCustomBitmapCodecWIC'. So I am obviously doing something fundamentally wrong when I am either sending or receiving the stream.

Comment: You cannot really mix VCL and FMX in the same project. If you want to use `FMX.Graphics`, you have to use FMX for the entire project. You don't need to change the Server from VCL to FMX just to load an image, though. `FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.SaveToStream()` always saves in PNG format. In VCL, you can use `TPNGImage` to load the stream.

Comment: Changing the record on the Server side to use TPNGImage solved my problem. Your help was very much appreciated.